# Why does IIS run two URL's for the same site?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

When I run my asp.net webforms app in VS 2017, IIS express starts and when I look at the running applications in the task bar I see:

PID = 20100

then, I see the same site name *twice*, once for http://localhost:62348/
then again for https://localhost:44321/

https://localhost:44321 is what Chrome uses for the page I have set as the start-up page, why the other port ? where is it coming from ?

Can someone *please* explain why there are two different ports and one is secure while the other is not ??

Comment: I've a hunch this a config error, since I fired up a brand new web application project, ran it and only got one IIS express URL / port running.

Comment: Different projects created under different conditions can end up with different IIS Express configuration files, so their settings (site bindings) naturally vary https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Well, actually, if you run both http and https? Sure, you have two choices here - one connection and process is encrypted and secured - the other is not. Quite sure this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in appsettings.json file
if you want only https you can use httpsredirect to force your application to only use https url

Answer (score 0):

When you use the IIS Express, Visual Studio will assign one random free port for your application to host. you can launch this application by just right click on IIS Express Icon on system tray icon and then select "Show All Applications". This will open a dialog where you can see all the running application on IIS Express, this is what you see http://localhost:62348.

When you enable SSL in "Project Properties", then set "**SSL Enabled = True**", now run the application, you can see there is different URL for SSL and non SSL for the single site, this is what you see https://localhost:44321.

If you are wondering where does these information getting stored, then you have to give a look inside your Web project file (.csprog). open the project file in any editor, you will find a section called . Project Extension has a child section called  Web Project Properties, where you can see all the setting.